# What's the best way to make a PHP-generated table responsive?

Tags: javascript, layout, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a PHP-site, which is connected with a SQL-database. The database is displayed on the page in a table (see code below).

```php
<?php
require "connect.php";

$query = "SELECT * FROM table";

$res = mysqli_query($db, $query);

echo '<table border=1>';
while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>". $line['date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>". $line['team1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>". $line['team2'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>". $line['result'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

The table looks well if you open the website on a computer, but if you open it on your phone, the table is to big (it has to many columns) to be displayed completely without scrolling. 
So I thought about a new structuring if you open the page on a mobile phone, but I don't want to have 2 different documents, only one. I'm not sure yet how the mobile structuring will look like, but that doesn't matter at the moment.
My question is: What would be the best way to recognize whether the device is a computer or a phone. 
One way would be to find out the width of the device using JavaScript and, depending on the recognized width, executing the right PHP-code. It would look like this:

```js
var width = screen.width;
if (width > 1000) {
   document.write("<?php either this ?>");
}
else {
   document.write("<?php or this ?>");
}
```

Another way would be to output the width of the screen into a hidden input-form. Then PHP could store this value in an variable and, depending on the value, executing the right PHP-code. So the difference to way number 2 would be that I use the PHP-if-command and not the JavaScript-if-command.

Comment: I probably wouldn't do this with PHP. Instead, look into responsive CSS such as Bootstrap.

Comment: The point is that I want to use a different layout and not a different design, so I don't think a responsive would help?

Comment: @Meiki  When you say "a different layout and not a different design", how are the two different to you?  What exactly do you mean by "layout" and what exactly do you mean by "design"?  To me, the two would be synonyms.

Comment: _"My question is: What would be the best way to recognize whether the device is a computer or a phone."_ Look up responsive design and media queries. And as others have said, Bootstrap

Comment: Ok, by "design" I mean pure css. Different colors, floatings, filters etc. By "layout" I mean the structuring of the document, so in this case the computer-version consists of 4 columns and some rows and the mobile-version consists of e.g. the first column as the heading of a fold-out div, so you see the other 3 columns if you "open" the div first. I hope you understand what I mean :/

Comment: try media query of CSS instead. its easy to use.

Comment: Ok I replaced the word "layout" with "structuring", since this was misleading.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way: Use `div` tags with classes instead of `table`, `tr` and `td`, then apply the table properties to them via CSS, and then create one or more media queries which replace the table-like CSS with regular block elements, that way putting the table cells in lines above each other:

(note: use "expand snippet" and then drag your window below 600px width to see the result in the snippet. The snippet doesn't contain any PHP, but rather an example of the parsed HTML code)

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .table, .row, .cell {
    display: block;
  }
  .cell:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"> date1 </div>
    <div class="cell"> team1 </div>
    <div class="cell"> team2 </div>
    <div class="cell"> result1 </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"> date2 </div>
    <div class="cell"> team3 </div>
    <div class="cell"> team4 </div>
    <div class="cell"> result2 </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"> date3 </div>
    <div class="cell"> team5 </div>
    <div class="cell"> team6 </div>
    <div class="cell"> result3 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```